# retrieving json data from mysql and php into jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am trying to bring mysql data into jquery by using php, I get the data into a JSON format like this.

```
{"uid":"33","title":"Apple, Peach, Grapefruit","ing1":"apple","qty1":"1","meas1":"whole","ing2":"peaches \/ halved and","qty2":"2","meas2":"each","ing3":"grapefruit \/ peeled","qty3":"2","meas3":"each","ing4":"","qty4":"0","meas4":"each","ing5":"","qty5":"0","meas5":"each","ing6":"","qty6":"0","meas6":"each","ing7":"","qty7":"0","meas7":"each","ing8":"","qty8":"0","meas8":"each","ing9":"","qty9":"0","meas9":"each","ing10":"","qty10":"0","meas10":"each","servings":"2","benefits":""}
```

using this following code:

```
require_once'connect.php'; 
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE uid = '$uid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$num_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$data = json_encode($row);
echo $data;
}
```

I am using jquery .get to pull it into the web page with this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var id = location.search;
uid=id.substring(4);
$.get('../jqm_juicing/data/get_json.php?uid=' + uid,function(data, status){
$("#display").append(data);
});
});
```

It displays the json data as above.  I would like to be able to access the different elements individually, how do I do that?

Comment: Can't you use $.each js function?

Comment: If you mean the key and value pairs under elements, you can simply use data.key etc..

Comment: Is there more than one row echoed ?

Comment: Oh, got you. You'll need to iterate through your data, which will contain more json objects. You can use $.each jquery, or foreach() vanilla.

Comment: Hienz, I tried that data.title and it comes up blank, any other ideas?

Comment: Louys, only one row is displayed, I have it set in my query with a uid, that part is functioning correctly.

Comment: sir i think you just add the full **http** link and replace ../jqm_juicing/data/get_json.php the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap it with `<script>` tags, and declare it as a variable, you will have it.

```
require_once'connect.php'; 
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE uid = '$uid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$num_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);

echo "<script>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data = json_encode($row);
  echo "var myJson=" . $data;
}
echo "</script>";
```

Now in your main page scripts, you can access this JSON like any other normal JSON.
Here is an interval that you can place anywhere in your main page scripts:
*It is just to test this ;)*

```
var checkJson = setInterval(function(){

  if(typeof(myJson.uid)!="undefined"){

    clearInterval(checkJson);

    console.log("myJson uid: " + myJson.uid);
    console.log("myJson title: " + myJson.title);
    // etc...

  }else{
    console.log("JSON not loaded yet.");
  }

},500);
```

Comment: thank you, that did the trick.  I am not actually a programmer/coder, more of a hobbyist, would you explain what is going here please?

Comment: Instead of passing the JSON as a string in the `#display` div, It is now a JavaScript variable injected in your page. The interval is because there is a small delay to get the result... So you have to wait for it and repeately check until it is loaded.

Comment: So depending on what you want to do with the JSON, there may be different approach. But once injected, the JSON is there an you can access it many times.

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery, add JSON.parse() before you append (data).

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var id = location.search;
    uid=id.substring(4);
    $.get('../jqm_juicing/data/get_json.php?uid=' + uid,function(data, status){
        $("#display").append(JSON.parse(data));
    });
});
```

I just changed this line:

```
$("#display").append(JSON.parse(data));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the json data to use json response jquery parse function. json data using this function
jQuery.parseJSON()

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/